# Angular 5 Material - Sticky Div / component inside Dialog

Tags: angular, css, angular5, angular-material-5

This is my material dialog.

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Title</h1>

<mat-dialog-content>

  <app-container> </app-container>

</mat-dialog-content>
```

In the app-container component template there are 3 other components.

```
<app-container1> </app-container1>
<app-container2 class="sticky"> </app-container2>
<app-container3> </app-container3> 
<!-- app-container 3 contains a list of items iterated over *ngFor -->
```

The three containers are inside a scrollable MatDialog. I would like the app-container2 to be sticky or fixed in it's position so when you scroll in the dialog app-container2 is always seen.

```
.sticky {
   position: fixed !important; //position: sticky !important;
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help me out.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [host styles](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host)?

Answer (score 0):

Styling for the dialog panel and its contents needs to belong to the class that is specified with the 'panelClass' option for the dialog config:

```
.dialogPanel .sticky {
    position: fixed;
}

this.dialog.open(MyDialog, { panelClass: 'dialogPanel' });
```